# How to nest a navigationController inside of a UIPopOverController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

There are actually three views at play. My homeView, which is where I launch the picker from, which sets the StudyPickerController view as root to a navController, which is then presented inside of the popOverController. Then from within the StudyPickerController view, I need to push to the ScreenPickerController, a different view completely.

I have a UIPopOverController that is displaying the contents of a view that is a tableView. I would like to be able to push a new view with a viewController inside of this view, but as I will discuss, it is really close, but it just won't push!

So from my homeView, when the button is pushed, an action is called and this code is run:

```
self.studyPicker = [[[StudyPickerController alloc] initWithStudyArray:self.studyArray ViewNum:butto.tag] autorelease];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.studyPicker];   

_studyPicker.delegate = self;
self.studyPickerPopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController] autorelease];               

[self.studyPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(120,45, 10,10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

And this works pretty well! The popOverController displays the contents of my StudyPickerController without any problems. I get the feeling that I am indeed getting access to my navigationController because the frame of the popOverController has a bar at the top, instead of just being a thin border, it has a navigationBar.

So now when I want to select a row in this view, I would like to push to a new view, also with a tableView, with my navigationController. This is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSArray * array = [_studyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ScreenPickerController * picker = [[ScreenPickerController alloc] init];
    picker.seriesGUID = array;
    picker.viewNumber = viewNumber;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

It seems to me that this should be working! But alas, I press a row, and it highlights, and nothing happens.

I've been working on this all day, so it very well could be that I am just missing something, but I don't know what it is. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you should be doing [[ScreenPickerController alloc] init] instead of loading the controller from a nib file instead?  As an aside, as it's written, you're leaking the picker by not releasing/autoreleasing it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. The ScreenPickerController is a UIViewController, and it has a nib file associated with it, how could I do it different than what I have?

Comment: Something like [[ScreenPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScreenPickerController" bundle:nil];

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I put that in there, but no luck...

Comment: init will by default choose the xib file with the same name.  Test it out and then refactor your code to rip out xib names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are two classes involved here: your homeView class and the StudyPickerController. I'm guessing the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method would be in the homeView class?

In that case, `self.navigationController` is trying to access the navigation controller that homeView is in, *not* the navigation controller you put into the popover. Since homeView isn't even in a navigation controller, the accessor returns nil.

Instead, you will want to use something like `[self.studyPicker.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];`.

Comment: Ok you had the right idea. Instead of self. I did super. and it worked!